# UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath HockeyApp Crash Report

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, hockeyapp

I am using HockeyApp for crash reporting and getting the following crash.  I am unable to reproduce the crash.  Can this be due to animating the scroll in the UICollectionView?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV

Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x66dbc2408

Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:

Selector name found in current argument registers: indexAtPosition:

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000198e8c0b0 objc_retain + 16

1   UIKit                                0x00000001898bade0 -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 248

2   UIKit                                0x0000000189acb1dc -[UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 256

3   MyApp                          0x000000010016c33c -[CalendarView scrollToDate:animated:] (CalendarView.m:183)

4   MyApp                          0x00000001001607cc __56-[CalendarViewController _updateHighlightedDateRange]_block_invoke (CalendarViewController.m:577)

5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001996916e8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20

6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001996916a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 12

7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000199696db0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1840

8   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001842781f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8

9   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000184276060 __CFRunLoopRun + 1624

10  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001841a4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380

11  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018f3e0088 GSEventRunModal + 176

12  UIKit                                0x00000001898bcffc UIApplicationMain + 200

13  MyApp                          0x000000010015c2a4 main (main.m:12)

14  libdyld.dylib                        0x00000001996c28b8 start + 0
```

Comment: have you find any solutions yet?

Comment: No, I have not yet